# Android-Phonegap-Jquery Mobile: form submit does not work 2nd time

Tags: android, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova, form-submit

I am developing mobile webapplication using Phonegap and JQM. I have Page with form with Search Input which submits to self and suppose to get data from using AJAX Query from server.
I enter a text and hit enter on phone, form submit event handler executes but it does not execute on subsequently whenever I hit enter on phone keyboard. I tried to add event handler in pagainit, pagecreate but did not help so added script to page itself but its the same behavior. Whats the right way to add handler to form.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mobileinit.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>

</head>
<body >

        <div data-role="page" id="index" >
            <form id="indexsearchform" method="post"  >

             <div data-role="content">

                <input type="search" id="txtbusinesssearch" placeholder="Search Business...."/>

              </div>    

            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                $('#indexsearchform').submit(function(){
                                        alert("hi");

                });

            --></script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there's no second alert message in your form is simply because the form you see after clicking #submit button for the first time isn't the same form. It looks the same, it has the same markup, but that's because jQuery mobile submits the form to the same address you're on and displays the result.

There are two options what you can do

1)Use `<form id="callAjaxForm" data-ajax="false">`

The behavior after adding data-ajax="false" to the form results in jQuery mobile to submit the form regular way, so the page actually get reloaded and the click handler for #submit button works every time.

2)Just change the type="submit" to type="button"
And the normal button will work fine :)

Comment: Thanks for reply but if new form get created every time then .live should have worked. But I found that following  code without .die would execute submit handler multiple times $('#index').live('pageinit', function(event){
 $('#indexsearchform').live('submit',function(){
 $('#indexsearchform').die();
  alert("hi");
 });
}); . With .die I get the behavior I want. It looks like for every .lve there has to be .die function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="indexsearchform" method="post" onsubmit="functionToBeExecutedOnSubmit();" >
```